# PatternConverter class in log4j2.12.1 doesn't contain constructor

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

PatternConverter class is declared as abstract class in log4j 1.2.17 and in log4j 2.12.1 it is declared as interface. That interface doesn't contain constructor which I have to pass loggingEvent in that constructor. Do anyone help me to migrate from 1.2 to 2.11

Comment: The official migration guide would be your best help https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html

Answer (score 0):

Log4j 2 uses plugins. The documentation on how to create a custom PatternConverter is at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#PatternConverters. That should contain all the information you need. You can also look at any of the converters in https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/tree/release-2.x/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern.